# Associating Custom LDAP Query with View

Tags: views, authentication-authorization

Versions:
->Drupal 7.10
->LDAP Authentication/Authorization/Servers/Query/Views 7.x-1.0-beta5
->Views/Views UI 7.x-3.3

---

I'm attempting to configure a View via the Views UI module to support a custom LDAP query defined in the LDAP Query module. The example they provide depends on the existence of a query with the machine name of "ad_users", and does function when I define a query with that name, but there doesn't seem to be a way to alter this or point a view toward an arbitrary query.

I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something. It seems illogical that the Views plugin wouldn't let one point a View toward an arbitrary LDAP Query. The question is how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In the *Advanced* section of the view, click on *Query Settings* and choose your own LDAP Query from the select list that appears.

Comment: explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a successful connection to an LDAP server and you have added an LDAP Query to build your view on.

Just like cafuego said first make sure to select the LDAP  Query to use for the view in the view settings dialog.

Within the view add an "LDAP Query: LDAP Attribute" field and select the attribute to add from the LDAP Query Attribute Dialog.

If you are have issues then try changing the Query Settings and saving the view again. I had to do this in order for my view to start pulling correctly.